# C++ Динамическое выделение памяти для массива

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Всем привет! Нужно используя динамическую память создать Массив 'А' и внести эти элементы в массив 'В' в порядке возрастания. Не могу понять, как их внести и записать в порядке возрастания. Может я и не правильно начал.

```
#include <iostream>

    using namespace std; 


    int main()
    {
        int n = 0;
        int size = 4;
        int *A = new int[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            cin >> A[i];
            cout << A[i] << " ";
        }


    }
```

Comment: Отсортируй его.

Comment: А ну кажется понял, как сделать, попробую.

Comment: заносите в массив В первый элемент, если второй элемент больше, запишите на свою позицию, если меньше, то большие вправо на одну позицию и заносите в освобожденное место и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int n = 0;
int size = 4;
int* A = new int[size];
int* B = new int[size];

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cin >> A[i];
}

// Сортировка пузырьком
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; j++) {
        if (A[j] > A[j + 1]) {
            int tmp = A[j];
            A[j] = A[j + 1];
            A[j + 1] = tmp;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    B[i] = A[i];
    cout << B[i] << " ";
}

delete[] A, B;
```